# Constructor if statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a class `Vehicle` and a constructor for that class. The class is characterized by engine volume, year made and type of vehicle (it can only be "car" or "motorcycle" ). What bugs me about the last bit is how I should implement it. The user will input `c`(car) or `m`(motorcycle). My question is what's the best way to implement this?

Should I make an `if` statement within the constructor (e.g. if passed parameter of vehicle type is 'c', then make a String 'Car', or 'Motorcycle' for m).

or

Do a similar thing in the `public static void main` method, where I would make `String Car` or `String Motorcycle` (depending on input) and just pass it on to the constructor.

Comment: An enum? This sounds like a very typical application of enums.

Comment: Not that advanced in Java, beginner's course, pretty sure I need a rookie solution.

Comment: Well, I thought enums could be simple. :-) I see, of course, if you haven’t learned enums, you’re not supposed to use them. In that case I think I’d just store the char ('c' or 'm') inside the `Vehicle` object. If you want to be little bit advanced, you may put an if statement in a getter and/or toString method so you can still print out "Car" or "Motorcycle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should not put logic inside constructor as constructor is used for initialization purpose. So this way you should put the if condition inside main method then pass the final values to the constructor.

Comment: Okay, so basically, I should already be passing a predefined value to a constructor, never inside of one. E.g. `Vehicle v= new Vehicle(2200, 1976, "car");`

Comment: The basic idea here is put least logic inside constructor as it is against conventions.Yes,you should pass predefined value to constructor.

Comment: Is that only me? A convention of avoiding logic in constructor is new to me. I sometimes have my constructor call methods that contain logic. What would be the problem with it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to create abstract class Vehicle and then extend it with classes Car and Motorcycle.

```
abstract class Vehicle
 {
     //Common logic here
 }
 class Car extends Vehicle
 {
    //Car-specific stuff here
 }

 class Motorcycle extends Vehicle
 {
 }
```

You should create the corresponding instance in your main method for now, later you may use [factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) to create class-specific behavior

Comment: The whole trick is not to make subclasses. I was just curious what's the best good-practice way to pass the `String` problem. The car and the motorcycle will still be the same object, the only difference is one is gonna have a `String` that says Car, the other 'Motorcycle'.

Comment: If so I'd recommend to really use ENUMS - if you don't need any logic inside and just a flag for vehicle type the enum is the right solution.

Comment: Oh, well I've yet to get to enums. I'm a newbie, just starting out, but I believe the enum solution will come in handy later. Thank you :)

Comment: I agree with the first comment, subclassing is overkill for the requirements if I understand them correctly.